# This question is about motor power requirements

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, friction, torque, power

If I have a motor that has a power of 20 kilowatts, does that mean that the motor can produce a torque of 10k newtonmeters at 2 rpm, or analogously a torque of 2 newtonmeters at 10k rpm since the formula for power output is torque multiplied by angular velocity. I just don't understand power.

Another question: If a car weighs 100kg, and it should accelerate at 10 m/s^2, with disregard for drag and friction for the sake of a simple explanation, how many watts of power does the motor need to be able to produce?

Now, i understand that a watt is a watt and a joule is a joule (and yes joule is a unit of work not power but it serves the point...) no matter where or in what form it is found, but i just can't wrap my head around how you would apply this to an actual real life example. How much power is required of the motor to move the car has yet to be explained sufficiently to me. Maybe you can!

Comment: All real motors have torque curves, with torque changing with rpm. Easy to sense driving a manual transmission car.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd question is not answered above.

Power is 'rate of doing work' and in this case is 'rate of increase of KE' (assuming no losses!)

Now -

KE = 0.5 mv^2

and

v=  at  (for uniform acceleration and initial v=0)

So KE = 0.5 m a^2 t^2

The derivative (rate) of work (= power) is therefore m a^2 t

Thus the power to create that acceleration is not constant and increases with t, or conversely, given constant power, the acceleration reduces with t.

This is why a car cannot continue to accelerate indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

Question one: yes indeed, both conditions you describe represent the same *power*. Now, why choose one over another? Well, some applications work best with high speed and low torque (like a wood-cutting *router* or a dental drill) while others work best with low speed and high torque (like a *power winch* for dragging logs or the 20-foot diameter propeller on a cargo ship).

Other applications require a *variety* of torque and RPM combinations and for them, the designer includes a multi-speed *transmission* which allows the best combination to be selected. This is why car engines have 5-speed transmissions attached to them, and why racing bikes have 21-speed derailleurs on them.

Second question: Use Newton's law f = ma, using the force applied to the road surface by the rotating tire as f.

Comment: thank you very very much for taking the time to answer. you finally made me understand everything. thank you!